# Search data in html using Groovy and XmlSluper

Tags: html, parsing, url, groovy

I want to parse one URL and to find a specific tag and to read it's text, so for testing purposes I downloaded the page and do what I want and everything works fine, but when I tried with the URL, not File. Nothing happens, so what can be the problem.

```
String newsPage= "http://www.dnes.bg/sport/2014/01/01/chelsi-s-pyrvi-transfer-za-novata-godina.211048"
def page = new XmlSlurper(new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()).parse(newsPage)
        def articleNode = page.'**'.grep{it.name().equals("DIV")&&it.@class.toString().equals("article-text")
            println it.name()
            println it.@id
            println it.@class
            println it.text()
        }
```

The last *printlns* are for testing purposes and I found that not all tag's names are printed. So the searched tag **article-text** was not printed, because it was not found. I can't understand why the name of some tags are printed, but the others are not. Part of the output of the tag's name was :

```
HTML
HEAD
META
TITLE
META
META
META
META
META
META
LINK
...
```

There is LINK tag after TITLE tag but it's name is not on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd...works for me...

I changed it to:

```
def articleNode = page.'**'.find { it.name() == "DIV" && 
                                   it.@class == "article-text" }
println articleNode.text()
```

And it seems to work as well...

Comment: Tried and now works. Strange.. And one more question? Is there a way to show all attributes of given element with XmlSluper if we don't know their names.

Comment: Ouu thanks again. I asked because in the html **img** tag has src,alt,title attributes but now when I print img's attributes with attributes() only src and alt presents and alt is empty. I am wondering why. Is this some CyberNeko's change of the html?